# vadliator is not working and return 200 OK

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

trying to validate it but it seems like it is not making validation and return 200 OK. I do not know what is happen with this. When I debug it, I can not still find the reason why it is not working.

rules from service class

```
protected $rules = [
        'username' => 'required|max:20|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required',
        // **in Production **
        // 'password' => [
        //     'required',
        //     'min:6',
        //     'regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/',
        //     'confirmed'
        // ],
        /**
         * Three of the five rules. 
         * English uppercase characters (A – Z)
         * English lowercase characters (a – z)
         * Base 10 digits (0 – 9)
         * Non-alphanumeric (For example: !, $, #, or %)
         * Unicode characters
         */

        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'phone' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|min:5',
        'role' => 'required',

    ];
```

validate method from service class

```
    public function validate($user)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($user, $this->rules);
        $validator->validate();

    }
```

store method in controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validate = $this->userService->validate($request->all());

        if ($validate->fails()) {

            return response()->json(['message' => $validate->failed()], 400);
        } else {
            try {
                $user = $this->userService->createUser($request);
                return response()->json($user, 201);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: your goal is to have your code decoupled in several class files right? If so, why do not make use or Request classes? This could handle your validation logic without the need to manually check if validation passed. If you agree I can guide to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing your `validate()` method in your service class so that it returns something, for instance:

```
public function validate($user)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($user, $this->rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        /* Here you can also return something like 
            return redirect('yourView')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
        */
        // Or you can simply
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And then in the controller you can check it like:

```
$validate = $this->userService->validate($request->all());

if ($validate)
{
    // Validation was successfull
} else {
    // Validation was not successfull
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not validate your request in a service class, but use Larvel's [Custom Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation) , which allows you to just specify the rules, it will handle the failing scenario (Returning back your browser and setting `$errors` variable in your template, or sending a proper JSON response).

Basically you'll have

```
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
    // if you reach here, validation passed.
    try {
        $user = $this->userService->createUser($request);
        return response()->json($user, 201);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
    }
}
```